# WPF My view model (or so I think it is) doesn't update if my insertion point is still in the control

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a newbie in WPF. I just learned the INotifyPropertyChanged but I don't know if I used it properly.

I have a LoginPage, I bound the UserNameTextBox's Text property to my object (which I think is the view model)

```
<UserControl x:Class="DentalThesis.Pages.LoginPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="User Name: " Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Password: " Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>


        <TextBox x:Name="UserNameTextBox" Text="{Binding UserName}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" PreviewKeyUp="UserNameTextBox_OnPreviewKeyUp"/>
        <PasswordBox x:Name="LoginPasswordBox"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" PreviewKeyUp="LoginPasswordBox_OnPreviewKeyUp"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="NotificationTextBlock" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

        <Button x:Name="LoginButton" Content="Login" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Click="LoginButton_OnClick"/>
        <Button x:Name="ExitButton" Content="Exit" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Click="ExitButton_OnClick"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I have a method in my code behind that verifies the UserNameTextBox's Text. The code is fine if I click the LoginButton, but since I also used the event 
UserNameTextBox_OnPreviewKeyUp, my view model is not yet updated so long as the insertion point does not leave the UserNameTextBox, so my userMgr.Entity.UserName's value is "" instead of the string that I typed in the UserNameTextBox. It will only update the model if I move the insertion point somewhere

Here is the code behind for my LoginPage:

```
public partial class LoginPage 
    {
        UserMgr userMgr = new UserMgr();
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = userMgr.Entity;
            IsVisibleChanged += AutoFocus;
        }

        void AutoFocus(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle,
                new Action(() => UserNameTextBox.Focus()));
            }
        }

        public void LoginMethod()
        {
            //LoginButton.Focus(); <-- this is a remedy, but I want to remove this
            if (userMgr.AuthenticateUser(userMgr.Entity))
            {

                SessionHelper.FormChosen = ChosenForm.FormLogin;
                NotificationTextBlock.Text = "";
                Exiter();
            }
            else
            {

                NotificationTextBlock.Text = "Error login";
            }
        }

        private void Exiter()
        {
            Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
            if (parentWindow != null) parentWindow.Close();
        }


        private void LoginButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoginMethod();
        }


        private void ExitButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Exiter();
        }

        private void UserNameTextBox_OnPreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Key.ToString() == "Return")
            {
                LoginMethod();


            }
        }

        private void LoginPasswordBox_OnPreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key.ToString() == "Return")
            {
                LoginMethod();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754356(v=vs.110).aspx, when binding the property Text of a TextBox, by default, it updates the target property only when it lost focus.
To update every time a user changes the text, you must set the property UpdateSourceTrigger of the binding to PropertyChanged, like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="UserNameTextBox" Text="{Binding UserName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ... />
```

---

BTW, assuming you are implementing the pattern MVVM, for the actions like the Login you are doing, is cleaner to use Commands instead of event handlers on the code behind. I recommend you this article, it could be long but its useful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx